# How can I have the mouse in "Wait" mode when run code

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function that will call get data from REST API, then filter data and display to table.

The whole process will take some time, so I would like to have the mouse be in "Wait" mode (displayed as an hourglass in old Windows) to let user know that the process is still running.

However, I have try all of the methods I found on internet, and can still not be able to have the mouse turn into a "Wait" mode. The mouse is simply a hand mode (when hover over the search button) until the process is finished.
The code I have tried is as below:

```
// Simply set mouse to "Wait"
const waitMouse = function(){
    $('html, body').css("cursor", "wait");
}

// This function will be do most of the process
const SearchData = function(){
  // Call Rest API
  // Filter data
  // Set to JSON array that map to the displayed table
  $('html, body').css("cursor", "auto"); //If delete this line, the mouse will change to "Wait" mode after the process finish
}

// This function will be do most of the process
const SearchData2 = asyn() => {
  // Call Rest API
  // Filter data
  // Set to JSON array that map to the displayed table
  $('html, body').css("cursor", "auto"); //If delete this line, the mouse will stay in "Wait" mode
}

// This function will be called when click search button
function Run(){
  // I did not use all methods below in one go, only 1 method each time

  //Try 1 - Simply call the function
  $('html, body').css("cursor", "wait");
  SearchData();

  //Try 2.1 - Use setTimeout on main function
  $('html, body').css("cursor", "wait");
  setTimeout(SearchData(), 1000);

  //Try 2.2 - Use setTimeout on both
  setTimeout(function(){$('html, body').css("cursor", "wait");}, 500);
  setTimeout(functionCall2(), 2000);

  //Try 3.1 - Use some fancy function name Promise
  Promise.resolve(0).then(() => waitMouse()).then(() => functionCall());

  //Try 3.2 - Use Promise in another way
  Promise.resolve(0).then(() => waitMouse());
  Promise.resolve(1).then(() => functionCall());  

  // Try 4 - Use CSS (Delete )
  $('body').addClass('wait');
  functionCall();
  $('body').removeClass('wait');

  //Try 5 - Use asyn
  $('html, body').css("cursor", "wait");
  SearchData2();
}
```

None of the above work.

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Did you try to define the cursor for another element - maybe the button? When i test the solution from @OluwafemiSule with `$('html, body')` instead of `searchBtn$` the cursor doesn't change over the button...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the cursor to wait before the asynchronous operation performed with the `Promise` object.

Revert the style to the default once the `Promise` resolves or rejects.

Here is an example:

```js
 const longRunningOperation = () => new Promise(
   resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({foo: 'bar'}), 5000)
);
$(document).ready(function(){
  const searchBtn$ = $("#searchBtn");
  const waitElements$ = $("html, #searchBtn");
  const result$ = $("#result");

  searchBtn$.on("click", function() {
    waitElements$.css("cursor", "wait");
    
    longRunningOperation()
    .then(json => result$.text(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4)))
    .then(() => waitElements$.css("cursor", "default"))
    .catch(() => waitElements$.css("cursor", "default"))
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="searchBtn">Search</button>

<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: As my webpage is auto-generated, with most of its element have neither id nor name, I have to use the below to get the element:
    const searchBtn$ = $('button:contains("Search")');
    searchBtn$.css("color", "red");
    searchBtn$.css("cursor", "wait");
However, for some reason, the color part worked, but the cursor did not.
I can see the Wait cursor flash rigth after the data was loaded to the screen, not right after the click.